# Keep value in textboxes after adding row

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i am currently working on to display the value in textboxes after adding row to the table. I am new to angular and seems i could not find the solution. At the moment, everytime i click on the Add button, the table will add new row but somehow the value that i have entered previously are gone. I need to make the value stays in the textbox every time the user adds new row.

Here is the source code that i have done:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxduqp

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You just remove the `name` from the form control if not required else you need to provide the unique name to each control.

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpq9nc

Comment: Do you know how can i not submit the value when there is any empty textbox by doing a checking in the configSubmit() function?

Comment: I can see the values in `styleConfig` after submission. I have updated the demo.

Comment: i dont want the values to be submitted when there is any textbox that doesnt have values. Maybe an alert when the user click on the submit button or just disable the submit button when there is empty textbox field.

Comment: In your case, you can use template driven validation. Refer this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation

Answer (score 1):

That happens when you have multiple inputs with the same name.

One way to fix it is by giving your input names a suffix of your iterator `i`:

```
<input ... [name]="'from' + i" ...>
```

Here is your StackBlitz corrected:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgdgpr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Do you know how can i not submit the value when there is any empty textbox by doing a checking in the configSubmit() function?

Comment: You should probably disable submit button with validators. Read https://angular.io/guide/form-validation and ask if you have any questions.